# Get value from json dimensional array in oracle

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, where-clause

I have below JSON from which i need to fetch the value of `issuedIdentValue` where `issuedIdentType` = `PANCARD`

```
{
    "issuedIdent": [ 
        {"issuedIdentType":"DriversLicense","issuedIdentValue":"9797979797979797"},
        {"issuedIdentType":"SclSctyNb","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"},
        {"issuedIdentType":"PANCARD","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"}
    ]
}
```

I can not hard-code the index value **[2]** in my below query as the order of these records can be changed. So want to get rid off any hardcoded index.

```
select json_value(
    '{"issuedIdent": [{"issuedIdentType":"DriversLicense","issuedIdentValue":"9797979797979797"},{"issuedIdentType":"SclSctyNb","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"},  {"issuedIdentType":"PANCARDSctyNb","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"}]}', 
    '$.issuedIdent[2].issuedIdentValue'
) as output 
from d1entzendev.ExternalEventLog 
where 
    eventname = 'CustomerDetailsInqSVC' 
    and applname = 'digitalBANKING' 
    and requid = '4fe1fa1b-abd4-47cf-834b-858332c31618';
```

What changes will need to apply in json_value function to achieve the expected result

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12c or higher, you can use `JSON_TABLE()` for this:

```
select value
from json_table(
    '{"issuedIdent": [{"issuedIdentType":"DriversLicense","issuedIdentValue":"9797979797979797"},{"issuedIdentType":"SclSctyNb","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"},  {"issuedIdentType":"PANCARD","issuedIdentValue":"078-01-8877"}]}',
    '$.issuedIdent[*]' columns
         type   varchar(50) path '$.issuedIdentType',
         value  varchar(50) path '$.issuedIdentValue'
) t
where type = 'PANCARD'
```

**[This returns](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=83c24cc726f5fa0d4427723fa400df49)**:

```
| VALUE       |
| :---------- |
| 078-01-8877 |
```

Comment: If i have to get 5 different array sets from same JSON then i will have to run 5 SQL statements. Isn't there any other solution in which i could get the expected result from json_value or any other single function...Just want to avoid multiple select statements

Comment: any suggestion on my previous comment?

Comment: @deltaforce: without seeing actual data, I can’t really tell. I would suggest that you ask a new question for this, providing proper sample data and desired results.